# react-router HashRouter wont render on android when in webpack-dev-server hot reload environment

Tags: android, webpack-dev-server, react-router-dom

react-routerV4's HashRouter won't render on android when in webpack-dev-server hot reload started Server Environment (the whole Router wont rendering), Everything works fine when connected from  apple, yet from Android the render works fine in production packet bundle, not in hot reload memory development.

I've been searching for a solution for a while, attached is a copy of project pj:

```
"scripts": {
"test": "webpack-dev-server --progress --hot --colors --config webpack.test.config.js",
"dev": "webpack --progress  --colors --config webpack.dev.config.js",
"sit": "webpack --progress  --colors --config webpack.sit.config.js",
"prd": "webpack --progress --colors --profile --json > compilation-stats.json--config webpack.prd.config.js"},"dependencies": {
"ajv": "^5.5.1",
"ajv-keywords": "^2.1.1",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
"babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
"exports-loader": "^0.6.4",
"font-awesome": "^4.6.3",
"history": "^2.1.1",
"imports-loader": "^0.6.5",
"react": "^16.0.0",
"react-addons-shallow-compare": "^15.5.2",
"react-day-picker": "^6.2.1",
"react-dom": "^16.0.0",
"react-router": "^4.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
"react-slick": "^0.15.4",
"slick-carousel": "^1.6.0",
"sprite-loader": "^0.3.6",
"svg-sprite-loader": "^3.0.5",
"uglify-es": "^3.2.1",
"uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.2",
"utf8": "^2.1.2",
"whatwg-fetch": "^1.0.0"},"devDependencies": {
"ali-oss": "^4.11.2",
"animate.css": "^3.5.1",
"babel-core": "^6.26.0",
"babel-eslint": "6.x",
"babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
"babel-plugin-import": "^1.1.1",
"babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "6.x",
"babel-preset-react": "6.x",
"babel-preset-stage-0": "6.x",
"co": "^4.6.0",
"copy-webpack-plugin": "2.x",
"css-loader": "~0.23.0",
"es5-shim": "^4.5.8",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
"fetch-ie8": "^1.4.2",
"file-loader": "^0.9.0",
"json-loader": "^0.5.7",
"less": "^2.7.1",
"less-loader": "^4.0.5",
"open-browser-webpack-plugin": "0.0.2",
"os": "^0.1.1",
"postcss": "^6.0.13",
"postcss-loader": "^2.0.5",
"postcss-pxtorem": "^4.0.1",
"rc-slider": "^8.2.0",
"rc-tabs": "^8.0.1",
"rc-tooltip": "^3.4.6",
"rmc-date-picker": "^6.0.5",
"rmc-picker": "^5.0.4",
"style-loader": "~0.13.0",
"url-loader": "^0.5.7",
"webpack": "^3.3.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.7"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

it's been solved by downgrading my webpack-dev-server to 1.16.5 version from 2.9.5, not sure why it wont render the entry file main.jsx at all in 2.9.5 in android. but some how the progress wont show up, its not a big issue for now